# Is XyMTeX still working for people?

Tags: chemistry, xymtex

I am trying to use `XyMTeX` for typesetting a variety of chemical reactions and keep getting errors, namely with

- \ChemEquation
- \LewisSbond
- \LewistetrahedralA or B
- electron shift arrows and
- Reaction schemes.

I have noticed that it doesn't handle white space well, at all.
For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\LewisTetrahedralA{0==C;1==A;2==B;3==X;4==Y}
\end{document
```

I either get errors in the code or crazy typesetting where things are very strangely aligned.
Common errors include

- You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
- Missing $ inserted.
- Missing number, treated as zero.
- Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
- Extra }, or forgotten $.

Answer (score 6):

The file `lewisstruc.sty` uses `\smash` in the assumption (no longer valid) that `\smash` doesn't initiate horizontal mode.

Simple fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% fix the issue with \smash
\def\dotnodimension{\hbox{\smash{\hbox to0pt{\hss.\hss}}}}
%%%

\begin{document}

\LewisTetrahedralA{0==C;1==A;2==B;3==X;4==Y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks. That's sorted it.